# Sync data and offline capabilities in redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, persistence, redux, flux

Id like to make a simple web todo app on react + redux. And I need to sync data somehow (realtime / push notifications... ). So when todo item is added on one device, its synced to another.

Also I want to persist data that is not synchronized with the server. For cases when the connection is lost and then the user closes the app.

What are the best practices to solve this problem? What is the best for redux?

Comment: I don't believe there is any blanket answer to this type of question.  If you are wanting real time data flow from the server you are needing a websockets based solution (look at [horizon.io](http://horizon.io/) as a cool new project to help with this).  Redux is always a good choice for data flow, but there are other options too.  Start simple and try to add libraries and features as and when you hit a problem and need them.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using IndexedDB for that purposes.

Below is the general architecture for the data sync using PouchDB (taken from the first link in the list):

[image: image from link [1]]

Here're some resources you can check out to get the general idea of how you can implement the desired functionality:

1. The example using web-sockets and PouchDB: 
   [Building real-time collaborative offline-first apps with react, redux, PouchDB and websockets](http://blog.yld.io/2015/11/30/building-realtime-collaborative-offline-first-apps-with-react-redux-pouchdb-and-web-sockets/#.V4KSKfmLS70)
2. The example using WebRTC and [redux-swarmlog](https://github.com/philholden/redux-swarmlog) library: [tutorial on egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-peer-to-peer-todomvc-over-webrtc-using-swarmlog)